# Pandas panel unable to complete operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am reading in 2 dataframes as dicts to a panel in order to identify changes, however, for some reason I am now getting the below error. I am not finding any changes that would account for this discrepancy.

Code:

```
#RUN DIFF FUNCTION NOW THAT WE HAVE OUR DATA STRUCTURED
diff_panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=change_old, df2=change_new))
diff_output = diff_panel.apply(report_diff, axis=0)
diff_output
```

Error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 #RUN DIFF FUNCTION NOW THAT WE HAVE OUR DATA STRUCTURED
>   ----> 2 diff_panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=change_old, df2=change_new))
>         3 diff_output = diff_panel.apply(report_diff, axis=0)
>         4 diff_output
>
> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: `pd.Panel` has been deprecated for over 2 years now. Are you able to work with a `MultiIndex`?

Comment: @ALollz I suppose I could, though I've never worked with a MultiIndex before.